# How to I transfer data from my sd card to my phone?

Tags: sd-card, file-transfer, data-transfer

I got a new phone and I want to transfer all of my non-google affiliated apps onto my new phone. I got an sd card and I installed my apps onto it, and then inserted the sd card into my new phone. However, the data on the sd card will not show up/open on my new phone.

My old phone was a LG Optimus L90, and my new phone is a Huawei P8

Answer (score 1):

Apps need to be installed, they can't be moved from phone to phone.

You will need to backup all your apps using any backup app from the play store. Your apps will be backed up as .apk files. Use a file browser and find the files either on the sd card or phone storage. Transfer the files to your new phone and install them one by one. Note that `.apk` files just contain the apps, not their data.

Alternatively, you can use Google's app restore feature. After resetting your new phone, login with your Google account in the setup page. There would be one step in the setup that would allow you to restore your apps from the play store (and, if an app supports it, also your data). Of course this requires that you did backup your device to Google before. It's quite dodgy sometimes and I don't rely on that.

If you need to backup app data, you can refer to the [backup tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info).